# Masquerading real module of a class

Tags: python

Suppose you have the following layout for a python package

```
./a
./a/__init__.py
./a/_b.py
```

inside `__init__.py` you have

```
from _b import *
```

and inside _b.py you have

```
class B(object): pass
```

If you import from interactive prompt

```
>>> import a
>>> a.B
<class 'a._b.B'>
>>>
```

How can I completely hide the existence of _b ?

The problem I am trying to solve is the following: I want a facade package importing "hidden" modules and classes. The classes available from the facade (in my case `a`) are kept stable and guaranteed for the future. I want, however, freedom to relocate classes "under the hood", hence the hidden modules. This is all nice, but if some client code pickles an object provided by the facade, this pickled data will refer to the hidden module nesting, not to the facade nesting. In other words, if I reposition the `B` class in a module `_c.py`, client codes will not be able to unpickle because the pickled classes are referring to `a._b.B`, which has been moved. If they referred to `a.B`, I could relocate the B class as much as I want under the hood, without ruining pickled data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
B.__module__= 'a'
```

Incidentally you probably want an absolute import:

```
from a._b import *
```

as relative imports without the new explicit dot syntax are going away ([see PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)).

ETA re comment:

> I would have to set the module explicitly for every class

Yes, I don't think there's a way around that but you could at least automate it, at the end of `__init__`:

```
for value in globals().values():
    if inspect.isclass(value) and value.__module__.startswith('a.'):
        value.__module__= 'a'
```

(For new-style classes only you could get away with `isinstance(value, type)` instead of `inspect`. If the module doesn't have to run as `__main__` you could use `__name__` instead of hard-coding `'a'`.)

Comment: That is probably a good solution I didn't think about, but I would have to set the module explicitly for every class. Is there a "better" trick ? (I mean, this is good enough, but just for curiosity)

Comment: and good point about the PEP. I am liable of forgetting it every time (I mostly work with python 2.4 for compatibility reasons)

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `__module__` variable for `Class B`

```
class B(object): pass
B.__module__ = 'a'
```

> For classes, functions, and methods, this attribute contains the name of the module in which the object was defined.

Or define it once in your `__init__.py`:

```
from a._b import B # change this line, when required, e.g. from a._c import B
B.__module__ = 'a'
```